# MS Graph API not able to access details of a sub folder of a public-root-folder

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I was able to access basic info of Child Folders of a Public Root Folder  using this endpoint:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/PublicFoldersRoot/childFolders](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser%7D/mailFolders/PublicFoldersRoot/childFolders)

How can I access details of one of these child folders?
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/PublicFoldersRoot/{Child-folder-ID}/childFolders](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser%7D/mailFolders/PublicFoldersRoot/%7BChild-folder-ID%7D/childFolders)

API response:

```
{
  StatusCode: 400, 
  ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Public folders are not supported with the Microsoft Graph API. Public folders aren't mentioned as a [distinguished folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-beta) in the documentation.

You can upvote this as a [feature request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35370430-public-folder-support-in-graph-api).